# Define Size of the crop

Tags: android, crop

I would like to crop an image. But I got a problem:

How to define a default size for the crop. I would like when the rectangle appears for the crop to define the size and the position of it.

Regards

Wazol

Comment: Have you even tried anything? If you did, tell us the code you're using please

Comment: I have tried the code using by selva. I have found only that but it's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

You can use this link also for your reference

Click [Crop image using rectengle](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/)!

```
   int targetWidth = 100;
      int targetHeight = 100;
      Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
   targetWidth, targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
 Path path = new Path();
    path.addRect(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);
     canvas.clipPath(path);
     canvas.drawBitmap( sourceBitmap,
       new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
     new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
   imageView.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
```

Comment: check it out the below link for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use Intent add Aspect Ratio  adding outputX and outputY parameter

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 250);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Comment: don't use this intent. CROP action DOESN'T exist in all Android devices, and some which exist, act differently. The best way to achieve this, is create a custom camera, with a defined width and height, so user while taking the picture, is cropping it.

Comment: There is no other way to crop the image that define width and height on a custom camera? I just want to define default size and position on a basic crop

Comment: Try this Link this May Help U  http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html